# Using carriage return or line feed to build message body with tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following tsql that sends db mail.  This works with one formatting exception.  The last two lines generated do not have a line feed or carriage return in the email body.  The data types are varchar(255) and varchar(300) respectively.

I have tried with and with out cast and I have tried CHAR(10), CHAR(13) separately and together.

Why does these last two NOT split into separate lines?

```
  DECLARE  @errMsg VARCHAR(max)

  -- review edit fact UMDNSID values and catch orphans with out parents in CategoryList
  select @errMsg = 

  '====================================================================' + char(10) + 
  'Orphan UMDNSID: ' + cast(ef.umdnsid as varchar(50)) + char(10) + 
   'Edit Fact VendorItemID: ' + cast(ef.vendoritemid as varchar(50)) + char(10) + 
   'Current VendorItem UMDNSID: ' + cast(ip.umdnsid as varchar(50)) + char(10) + 
   'Current VendorItem Category: ' + ipcl.categoryname + char(10) + 
   'Item Description: ' + ef.LongDescription + char(10) + char(13)

  from EditFact ef
  join itemprovider ip
  on ef.vendoritemid = ip.itemprovider_pk
  join categorylist ipcl
  on ipcl.umdnsid = ip.umdnsid
  where 1=1
  AND editstatusid = 0
  AND settled is null 
  AND ef.UMDNSID not in (
        select umdnsid from categorylist)

EXEC dbo.ProcessFile_SendMail @ProcessFile_id=0, @Subject='Orphan UMDNSID', @Message=@errMsg, @To='someone@email.com';
```

The email body ends up looking like the following and I expect a new line where you see **.

Orphan UMDNSID: 27854
Edit Fact VendorItemID: 4654178
Current VendorItem UMDNSID: 99936
Current VendorItem Category: Custom Packs **Item Description: TRAY CARDIAC CATH CUSTOM

Comment: It looks like it is skipping more than just the last two.  And where is the ====================================?

Comment: I took it out of the message because it formats text to a large font.

Comment: A reach but try casting ipcl.categoryname to varchar (even if it already is) as that is where it breaks

Comment: I already gave cast a try on both varchar columns - it didn't work.

Comment: Test a print(@errMsg).  The problem may be in ProcessFile_SendMail.

Comment: wow - your right - it is in the other proc.  Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing in the SendMail proc that manipulates the message.  I was able to fix the problem by adding a few blank characters at the very end of the message:  ef.LongDescription + '   ' + Char(10) + Char(13)

Comment: I always use char(13)+char(10) like: `DECLARE @CRLF char(2); SET @CRLF=char(13)+char(10); print 'line1'+@CRLF+'line2'+@CRLF+'line3'` stored in a local value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that was the final answer

Test a print(@errMsg).
The problem may be in ProcessFile_SendMail.